# Borders pushing floats to next line when resolution changed

Tags: css

I am making a navigation that needs buttons with borders on each side that needs to fill a certain space. The float based approach I've taken however, breaks when the resolution is changed on Chrome. I believe this is because the actual resolution is made less, thus the browser has to round, and the borders are always kept at 1px in this process...

How do you best get around this problem

http://jsfiddle.net/ctZKr/

```
<div id="contain">
  <div class="in"></div>
  <div class="in"></div>
</div>

#contain{
    width:200px;
}
.in{
    float:left;
    width:98px;
    height:100px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    background-color:yellow;

}
```

at 100%

[image]

at 90%:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#contain{
    width:200px;
}
.in{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    background-color:yellow;

}
```

By using box-sizing, you can contain the entire element (element, margin, padding, border) all within the set width of the element. Of course, you'll have to browser test and all, but as long as you're targeting ie8+, you should be fine.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctZKr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use css box-sizing like so:

```
.in {
   box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```